# How to lose only belly fat in 2 weeks

Tags: weight-loss, low-carb, bellyfat

**Me:**
I am 191cm 71kg.  I am fairly defined except my stomach.

**My training:**
I currently do heavy free weight sessions 4 times a week:  chest, back/arms, legs and shoulders/arms.

**My diet:**
High protein/medium carb diet of mainly turkey, fish, rice, potatoes and eggs.  No protein shakes (allergic).

I am going on holiday in 2 weeks and would like my stomach to look its best and it currently does not look great due to some bad eating.

So basically I want to drop as much fat on my stomach as is possible without loosing existing muscle tissue and am willing to work for it.

From the internet I have read interval workouts on treadmill/cross trainer and eliminating all carbs.

Does anyone have any ideas how to achieve this and fast?  Should I take a break from weight training altogether or just add interval training or what?

Comment: related: [Losing stomach fat without losing weight](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/24053/losing-stomach-fat-without-losing-weight?rq=1)

Comment: relates: [How to lose waist fat?](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/6663/how-to-lose-waist-fat?rq=1)

Comment: related: [Best way to lose stomach fat](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/27579/best-way-to-lose-stomach-fat?rq=1)

Comment: related: [What is the best thing to lose belly fat](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/19374/what-is-the-best-thing-to-lose-belly-fat?rq=1)

Comment: related: [remove belly fat but am already slim only belly fat](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/21097/remove-belly-fat-but-am-already-slim-only-belly-fat?rq=1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not going to lose "only belly fat", but maybe you meant to differentiate "fat" from "muscle"?

HIIT and a *very* strict diet will *increase* your odds of making a significant difference. Adding a thermogenic supplement may also help, but different people react to those in different ways, especially if you're already caffeine-tolerant.

I differ from Dave in that I'd not worry much about muscle mass--HIIT dings mass much less than long, steady-state aerobic work. Personally, I'd stay in the mid-range of both weight and reps, if anything tending towards higher reps, and aim for "ripped" rather than "bulky".

You're basically trying to cram typical "pre-contest" prep into a really short period of time--it's too late for mass, now it's about presentation.

Comment: Last paragraph is exactly how I see it.  I am happy with my muscle mass I just want to strip as much fat off now in the last 2 weeks as I can before my holiday.  Do I have to use the treadmill or can I use cross trainer, bike or rowing machine - as my joints are genetically sensitive.  I am starting HIIT today :)  I also eliminated all carbs from my diet except plain rice cereal in the morning.

Comment: @TheLearner Use whatever you want--I'm a rowing machine fan, plus it's always open.

Answer (score 2):

High intensity intervals and eliminating carbs sounds good to me. I'd pull back on the weights, staying on the high-weight, low-rep side, but not eliminate them.

If your goal were mine, I'd scour Martin Berkhan's [LeanGains](http://www.leangains.com/) for information to see if I can tweak anything further than the basics already mentioned.