# remove belly fat but am already slim only belly fat

Tags: workout, abdominals, bellyfat

i have lot of fat in my stomach area am trying to remove

- how do i remove belly fat without using equipment

am already slim and my weight is just `64kg` and `5.80` tall

can some one advice me what to do and what not to do to have a fat-free body

am trying to remove belly fat any methods

Comment: Spot reduction is a myth. And your question has been asked before.

Comment: http://fitness.stackexchange.com/a/24035/1039

Answer (score 5):

### Hi Sanoj,

At your current height and weight, you're not fat *([healthy weight](https://www.rush.edu/health-wellness/quick-guides/what-is-a-healthy-weight), [ideal weight based on height](http://www.medindia.net/patients/calculators/ideal_weightresultadult.asp), and [BMI calculation](http://www.nhlbi.nih.gov/health/educational/lose_wt/BMI/bmicalc.htm))*. As a result, I highly doubt that dieting would help you achieve your goal.

Since you're not fat and you have a belly fat, it's likely as a result of your current lifestyle *(unless it's a medical condition)*.

- Do you sit a lot *(especially with bad posture)*?
- Do you drink alcohol often?
- Do you walk with bad posture?
- Do you eat heavy dinner *(possibly right before sleeping)*?

These could be the culprits.

**First, clean up your meals.** You don't need to diet; just eat balanced meals *(containing protein, complex carbs, vegetables, etc)* with proper rationing. As the first answer has mentioned, ***abs are made in the kitchen.*** Don't eat junk!

**Second, you need to exercise more.** While it's true that spot reduction is a myth, your body will utilize stored fat wherever it can find it, and given that your overall body has a lower fat percentage, more fat will be taken from your stomach.

Also, in addition to burning off fat, exercises allow your abdominal muscles to be more activated, revealing the much cherished six pack as your belly fat reduces.

If you're really serious about exercises, you'll need some equipment *(dumbbells, barbell, etc)*. That being said, there are plenty of exercises that do not require any equipment.

- Sprinting *(or the lighter form, jogging)*
- Knee Jumping
- Body weight exercises such as push ups, squats, planks, burpees, etc

All these *(and more)* require no equipment and are very effective in keeping you fit *(and trimming your belly fat)*.

You can also obtain workout videos to help you. If you do, I recommend trying out ***P90X's Ab Ripper X video***; it's awesome!

**Third, clean up your lifestyle.**

- If bad posture is the culprit, walking with a good posture *(straight back, eyes forward)* naturally activates your abdominal muscles.
- If it's sitting a lot, reduce it and endeavor to always sit straight when you do. Also, you can substitute regular chairs with stability balls.
- If alcohol is the culprit, reduce your intake or switch to lower-calorie alcoholic beverages.
- Eat light dinner, especially if/when it's close to bedtime.

I'm certain there are still lots of causes and solutions I might have missed; however, it's more important to start somewhere soonest than trying to obtain all the possible answers before starting.

Good luck!

Comment: can you please help me what are healthy foods to reduce fat in body

Comment: I cannot exhaust the list; however, here's the direction you should go for: **lean proteins, vegetables, complex carbohydrates, fruits.** Make **water** your **primary source of hydration.** Have cheat food once in a while. Have fun with it :).

Comment: How does posture affect belly fat?

Answer (score 3):

Despite everything that is expressed by nutritionists and fitness gurus, the truth is we're all different, and we're all genetically programmed to deal with fat metabolism differently. Think about all the people you know, and how much their diets seemingly **don't** reflect what their size.

I say this at the beginning because people shouldn't always beat themselves up for carrying too much weight, it might be in large part thanks to your parents!

Now... all that said you CAN obliviously improve your chances of losing fat, but realise your stomach is one of the *last* places to give it up.

There is a saying, "Abs are made in the kitchen". Out of all the muscle groups, you can do more to highlight for your abs by the work you do outside of the gym.

Here's a list of things you can do before you consider exercising...

1. *Diet* - reduce your overall calories - to lose weight you need to expend more calories on a daily basis than you ingest.
2. *Diet* - reduce the amount of bad fats.
3. *Diet* - reduce carbs in general, especially fast metabolising sugary carbs - the type of carbs you find in soft drinks, biscuits, cakes etc.
4. *Diet* - eat more protein, slow GI carbs (vegetables & oats) and *good* fats.
5. *Diet* - make sure you drink plenty of water.
6. *Diet* - some people are more susceptible to gaining weight from lactose and / or gluten. Limiting both of these in my diet helped me in the past.
7. Sleep - it's crucial so make sure you get a good night. Whenever I don't have enough sleep, especially over several days, I always carry more weight in my abdomen.
8. Don't over exercise - when you exercise you raise your corisol levels. Cortisol isn't an enemy, but too much does influence weight, again especially around the abdomen. Personally, I think it's water weight and given enough rest / sleep I find it subsides. Your age, fitness level and the amount of exercise will impact on the amount of rest you require.
9. Exercise - Concentrate on cardio - remember your calories need to hit a deficit. Run, cycle, row, crossfit, stairmaster, circuit training. Even choosing normal everyday activities helps. Take the stairs instead and try walking / cycling to work.
10. Work your abs - ab pulldowns, leg raises (different positions), leg extensions, planking, bicycle kicks, crunches - there are lots of different exercises you can do.

I just want to stress that diet is very important when it comes to revealing abs. There are plenty of people with well defined abs who never workout, and it's just because they're skinny... but it's also likely they'll have skinny legs, arms too. On the flip side there are masses of folks who knock out hundreds do back breaking crunches 7 days a week and they're left scratching their head as to why they're not losing the belly!

Also, don't bother with diet potions or pills, there aren't any shortcuts. It takes a disciplined diet and exercise routine. And time.

Good luck!

Comment: thanks it was helpfull because when i was 16age i don't have fat in belly now am 22 and lots of fat ONLY on belly area