# Best way to lose stomach fat

Tags: weight-loss, workout-routines, bodyweight-exercises, push-ups, sit-ups

Anyone know of a daily workout that can get me slim whilst building muscle? I dont mean a full on workout like going to the gym because there is no gym around where i live. I also eat pretty healthy so wasnt really looking to diet. As of right now i do 20 push ups every hour, every day, yet after 1 week it has yeilded no results. It may be too early to tell if this method works but i would still appreciate other ideas.

Answer (score -1):

Your workout is ineffective, and possibly your diet, too. Let me tell you the possible results of your workout plan: Increased endurance, minimum fat loss, slight muscle gain, and possibility of an overuse injury. Also check your calorie intake, it should be about 2500(give or take 100 calories) if you are a mid height, 25 year old active male, assuming you are active because you're probably doing 280-340 push ups a day. Unfortunately, without a gym there is little chance you can build muscle easily. Perhaps you can lose fat if you eat enough but not too much, but 20 repetitions is nearing endurance training, my friend. I'm not trying to start a war here, but I honestly find it hard to believe you are nowhere near a gym unless you live in a forest, on a farm, etc. If you are near one, though, I would suggest purchasing a membership and lift weights on a regular basis, switching muscles worked every other day or something near that. Otherwise, you'll have to considering buying your own weights; but as good as it is, a bench press isn't your best option because it would be very disheartening to us if you got trapped under some weight in the middle of nowhere.

Comment: Thank you, i will consider observing my calorie intake. However, i meant what i said about there being no gym nearby. I live just outside Riggins, ID, where the nearest city is at least 50 miles away. I wouldnt mind doing running instead. Any suggested number of miles to run or time lengths?

Comment: @user21494 Running kills your joints. I would suggest doing a 1 hr. bike ride 5 times a week.

Comment: "Running kills your joints" seems like such a half-truth. If it were entirely true, there would be no sprinters or marathon runners.

Comment: @Alec Over long periods of time, it will speed up how fast the joints in your feet deteriorate. Perhaps the 30 year old sprinters will run like the Flash at that age, but it is their loss when they break at 50 and the rest of us break at 70.